# Probability of choose point in interval (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

Choose a point random uniformly in $(0,1)$. Then, this point divides the interval (0,1) into two sub-intervals.

1. Compute the expected length of the interval containing a fixed point $s \in [0,1]$.
2. Compute the expected distance of the randomly chosen point from $s$.

My approach: My intuition is that the expected length of the interval containing $s$ is 1/4, since on average the sub-intervals should be about length 1/2 each, and $s$ is in exactly one of them. I don't know how to mathematically prove this intuition if it's correct. I have no idea how to approach 2.

Comment: I think you are misreading the question. The answer should depend on the (fixed) $s$. If $s$ is near $0$ then the answer should be near $1/2$. But if $s$ is near $11/2$ it will be in the longer subinterval most of the time so I think the expected length of that interval would be greater than $1/2$.

Comment: @EthanBolker but how to compute?

Comment: Just added what I think is the correct answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X\sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$ and $L_X(s)$ be the length of the interval that contains $s$ and comes from the division by the point $X$. What we need to compute is $E(L_X(s))$, so having an expression for $L_X(s)$ as a function of $X$ should suffice to compute such expectation.

Observe that given the value of $X$, the length of the interval containing $s$ is $X\delta_{s<X}+(1-X)\delta_{s>X}$, so it follows that
$$E(L_X(s))=E(X\delta_{s<X}+(1-X)\delta_{s>X})=E(X\delta_{s<X})+E((1-X)\delta_{s>X}).$$
Finally note that
$$E(X\delta_{s<X})=\int_0^1 x\delta_{s<x}dx=\int_s^1 xdx=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s^2}{2}$$
$$E((1-X)\delta_{s>X})=\int_0^1 (1-x)\delta_{s>x}dx=\int_0^s (1-x)dx=s-\frac{s^2}{2},$$
so by adding you get that
$$E(L_X(s))=\frac{1}{2}+s-s^2.$$

Comment: Are you sure of this? When $s$ is near $0$ you get an expected length of $1$. That seems wrong to me.

Comment: When $s$ is near $0$, $s$ will be contained in the first interval in almost any case, but if it is contained in the second interval, that interval will be really close to be the entire interval. Such fact increases the mean a lot as seen in the first integral (which is the one that gets bigger when $s$ is small).

Comment: I'm still puzzled. Putting $s=0$ in your last formula yields and expectation of $1$. But the interval containing $0$ will have length $x$ and expected value $1/2$.

Comment: I just noted that the first integral is wrong! I will add extra steps in the computation just to make it clear. Also, this is consistent with your argument, my bad!

Comment: Looks good now, You should always check a computation like this in the  edge cases, That can reveal mistakes that you don't see when you just reread the argument.

Comment: I strongly agree.

Comment: @EstebanG. I'm not familiar with some of your notation. Is delta the indicator function here?

Comment: @Alborz. Yes, delta is the indicator function. In the context of probabilities and measure theory the usual notation for the indicator function is a capital 1 (\mathbbm(1)) however I couldn't make that work for some reason, so I used the typical Mathematical-Physics notation, which is a delta.

Comment: @EstebanG. having learned some about Indicator functions I came back to this problem and decided to tackle it on my own. Thanks for your detailed explanation, I arrived at the same answer so I felt like tackling the expected distance part of the question, and arrived at an answer of $\frac13$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. By symmetry, you can assume $s \le 1/2$. Then for random  $x$ the interval containing $s$ has length $x$ if $x > s$ and length $1-x$ if $x<s$.